How do I get these IntelliSense™ features in Vim?
Previously I used MS Visual Studio Code, which has this very nice feature called IntelliSense™. It works extremely well with HTML, CSS, and Javascript.
You can type ! and the html boilerplate would be inserted.
There were also many useful features like, you could press bg for background property.
For reference here's what I am talking about:

html-css-class-comoletion
intellisense


how can i create shortcuts to insert boilerplate code

Check out CoC: https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim

Requests for plugins are not on-topic here.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

You could be interested by snippet plugins that inserts boilerplate code by hitting small shortcuts.
For html and css emmet-vim is a good candidate.
Once you are familiar with snippet a popular snippet plugin that let you define your own or reuse somes of others is: ultisnip.
For code completion and LSP (language server) a good candidate is indeed coc.nvim.
After installing coc.nvim, for html, css and javascript you could be interested to install the corresponding coc.nvim extensions by running the following commands:
CocInstall coc-html
CocInstall coc-css
CocInstall coc-htmlhint
CocInstall coc-html-css-support
CocInstall coc-emmet
CocInstall coc-tsserver


this is cool, thanks

Glad you found what you were looking for :-) Welcome to Vim!

One of my favorite sentences from Vim's :help is from :help new-omni-completion:

This could also be called "intellisense", but that is a trademark.

There's no IntelliSense™ but there's something like it, which Vim calls omni completion.
This is your starting point for further research.
The typical way for a Vim plugin to provide completion is also to tap into the omni interface.
For web file types, omni completion will work out of the box as documented in :help ft-html-omni.
For other languages (e.g. from the C family), you will need a tags file which is created using an external program like Universal Ctags.
These tags files are text files which contain an index of each identifier and where it can be found in the source code.
I'm mentioning this because the first implementations of IntelliSense™ worked pretty much like that: when opening a project in your IDE, it would create a database of identifiers.
Very much like a tags file in a binary, proprietary format.
Let's take a step back and think about what an IDE is.
It's a bundle of development tools—one of which is an editor—wrapped together.
If the integration is good, users won't notice the stitches and code happily and productively.
This is very convenient, especially for novice developers, although seniors will also benefit from their IDE of choice.
There's nothing wrong with using an IDE.
The philosophy behind Vim is completely different.
Vim is an editor, plain and simple.
It offers interfaces to some developer tools from the open source ecosystem like the already mentioned Ctags, Cscope, GCC (and other C compilers), Make implementations, etc.
Vim's plugin system can be used to add features.
The burden of installing and configuring all these tools, however, is left to the user.
Visual Studio Code relies heavily on language server protocol (LSP) for completion and static code analysis.
There are several plugins which add LSP support to Vim, as well.
If IDEs are one-size-fits-all then setting up Vim is tailoring your own clothes.
It's more work, will be exactly what you wanted and fit perfectly.
(People will also likely think you're a nutcase but that's a different thing)
Coming back to the question, there are three ways to get IntelliSense™-like features into Vim:

Continue to use VS Code which you know and like. It has the real IntelliSense™. There's the VSCodeVim plugin to add Vim keybindings. This will give you hjkl but not some of Vim's more advanced features. If you don't miss them, it's fine.
Install one of these Vim-as-an-IDE solutions. Vivian's answer mentions some. From a user's perspective, it should make little difference whether you have an IDE with Vim keybindings or Vim with IDE features. You could still use all of Vim's features if you wanted.
Learn to use Vim from scratch and add tools when you need them. This is the most work but you will also learn a lot.

None of these options is inherently better or worse than the others.
Do some experiments, then make an informed choice.
If something doesn't work out for you, re-evaluate.

You put some hyphens in place of  em-dashes. Here's how to type them in different OSs.

I appreciate you improving my answer although I can't say I care too much about hyphens or dashes. Plain ASCII is expressive enough for me :-)
